# R - for loop to correctly pass variable to link

Tags: r, for-loop, rvest, rselenium

I'd like to **scrape** data from IMDB webpage with rating list of films.
I would like to do it for several pages, so after scraping content from first one, I need to open another one and repeat the process of scraping.
Initial page contains 250 films (this is the max which can be displayed) starting from rank 1 to 250. Next one should contain 250 films starting from 251 to 500.
Starting number can be passed in the link, but I have problem to correctly write and use for loop to pass 1 at first execution and than number incremented by 250.

Background:
I have tried if based on j value to increment the number by 250, but not really sure how to do it properly.

```r
#install required packages
install.packages("rvest")
install.packages("RSelenium")
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)

#open browser (Firefox in my case, but can be any, just change the value in line below from firefox to chrome, internet explorer)
rD <- rsDriver(browser=c("firefox"))
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

#set counter
counter=250

for (j in 1){
  j<-j+counter
  #set link for the webpage. 
  newURL<-"https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&release_date=,2018-12-31&count=250&start="
  startNumberURL<-paste0(newURL,j)

#open webpage in the browser
remDr$navigate(startNumberURL)

#read html code
strona_int<-read_html(startNumberURL)

#read rank section from the page
rank_data<-html_nodes(strona_int,'.text-primary')
#konwersja rankingu na text
rank_data<-html_text(rank_data)
#konwersja na numeric
rank_data<-as.numeric(rank_data)
}

#close browser
remDr$close()
#stop server
rD[["server"]]$stop()
```

Current result:
no error message.

In the loop initial link should be:
https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&release_date=,2018-12-31&count=250&start=1

Next one:
https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&release_date=,2018-12-31&count=250&start=251

**Update**
Thank you! Looks like it works almost perfect.

```r
ile<-seq(from=1, by=250, length.out = 3)
for (j in ile){ 
#open page in browser 
newURL<-"https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&release_date=,2018-12-31&count=250&start=" 
startNumberURL<-paste0(newURL,j)
```

But now additional question, how to add it to the data frame properly?

```r
#create dataframe
filmy_df_temp<-data.frame(Rank=rank_data) 
filmy_df<-rbind(filmy_df_temp) 
}
```

But it adds only latest execution.

Comment: `for (j in 1)` executes exactly once. To increment by 50, you can do something like `nums <- seq(1, by = 250, length.out = 10)`. Adapt at will. Then, `for(i in nums)`.

Comment: @rui-barradas,
Thank you!
Looks like it works almost perfect.

```ile<-seq(from=1, by=250, length.out = 3)
for (j in ile){
  #otworzenie strony w przegladarce
  newURL<-"https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&release_date=,2018-12-31&count=250&start="
  startNumberURL<-paste0(newURL,j)
```
But now additional question, how to add it to the frame properly?

```#create dataframe
filmy_df_temp<-data.frame(Rank=rank_data)
filmy_df<-rbind(filmy_df_temp)
}
```
But it adds only latest execution.

Comment: Please edit **the question** with that new code, it's much easier for us to read it.

Comment: @rui-baradas, done. I have updated the initial question.

Comment: I guess I have solved the problem, by adding empty data frame before loop. Looks like it is adding the data after each iteration.